# C# expanding panel

Tags: c#

[image]
<sub>(source: [ctho.org](http://www.ctho.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/error-dialog.png))</sub>

is there a similar control for c# i am trying to create a uploading app that will display further detail's of status on the update if the user clicks the details button but i dont know the name of that c# control and i fiddle a little with the panel control and coudnt find any options for it anybody know a name for it or a technique that will achieve the same behavior?

EDIT:
yes it's a desktop application windows specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a WinForms control that imitates that functionality natively.  You'll have to roll your own in one form or another, or find a third-party control.

One somewhat similar control that you might be able to coerce into doing your bidding is a SplitContainer oriented horizontally.  If you wire up a button to switch the visibility on the top panel on and off, that would produce an "expanding/hiding" sort of effect.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any control that does this because, frankly, it's so simple to implement yourself.  Just put a button on your form that says "more details", and in the OnClick event change the size of the panel (and form if necessary), marking the controls you want visible at the same time.

Comment: The only tricky bit is to handle anchoring and docking of the interior controls so that they behave correctly in both the unexpanded and expanded modes.

Comment: By default, if none of the controls have to move, there shouldn't be any issue with anchoring.  If you change the anchoring, then you will of course.  Perhaps your OK and Delete buttons anchored in the lower right, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a web app, there's an [Ajax Toolkit Control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx) for this or you could use [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle).